# How to Retrieve a Listing of Employee's Superiors in SQL

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Essentially, I have a table that lists an employee's number and the employeeNumber of who they report to.

```
 EmpNum | Name         | ReportsTo
 ---------------------------------
 1234   | John Smith   | 4523
 3245   | Annie Apples | 1234
 1532   | Bob Rogers   | 3245
 6574   | Dong Wong    | 1532
```

Etc. Etc. So Dong Wong's hierarchy would be: He reports to -> 1532 which reports to -> 3245 which reports to -> 1234.

(I'm new to SQL, so clean and understandable solutions would be appreciated)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at trying to solve this yourself?

Comment: Hmm, I realise you need a whole chain... how many tiers? Or could that be unlimited?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+sql

Answer (score 0):

By doing a join...

```
select e1.EmpNum, e1.name, e2.EmpNum as BossNum, e2.name as BossName from empTable e1 join empTable e2 on e1.ReportsTo=e2.EmpNum
```

The join can then be as long as you want, e3, e4... But doing it programatically is probably easier in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is standard ANSI SQL

```
with recursive report_tree as (
  select empnum, name, reportsto
  from employees
  where empnum = 6574 
  union all
  select c.empnum, c.name, c.reportsto
  from employees c 
    join report_tree p on p.reportsto = c.empnum
) 
select *
from report_tree;
```

If you want a "graphical" display, you can do something like this (still standard ANSI SQL):

```
with recursive report_tree as (
  select empnum, name, reportsto, name as report_path, 1 as level
  from employee
  where empnum = 6574 
  union all
  select c.empnum, c.name, c.reportsto, p.report_path || ' -> ' || c.name, p.level + 1
  from employee c 
    join report_tree p on p.reportsto = c.empnum
) 
select *
from report_tree
order by level desc 
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, cte is best for recursion. SO already has many solutions for such problem

```
create table #emp(
EmpNum int,
Name varchar(50),
ReportsTo int
);

insert into  #emp
values
(1234,'John',4523),
(3245,'Annie',1234),
(1532,'Bob',3245),
(6574,'Dong',1532)



with rec as (
    select #emp.ReportsTo, #emp.EmpNum, #emp.Name, 1 as level from #emp where Name = 'Bob'
    union all
    select  #emp.ReportsTo, #emp.EmpNum, #emp.Name, level + 1 as level from #emp    
    inner join rec   
    on #emp.EmpNum = rec.ReportsTo
)
select ReportsTo, EmpNum, Name, level from rec
where level = (select max(level) from rec)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```